# Linux Mint showing 1 thread per core in a 4 thread/core cpu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, cpu, amd, hyperthreading

I have a [Ryzen 3 3200g](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-3-3200g) and, when I do lscpu in a Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon OS terminal, the output says that I only have 1 thread per core. The Windows system's info accurately recognizes that my CPU has 4 threads, so is Linux Mint having some problem in recognize hyper-threading? If yes, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3200G specification:

> ```
> # of CPU Cores 4
> # of Threads 4
> ```

This means you have 4 CPU cores with 1 thread each, 3200G doesn't support [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) ([Hyper Threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is Intel "branding" of this feature) so you don't get multiple threads per core.

Your `lscpu` should say something like

```
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
```

and if you run some tool that shows CPU utilization (like `htop`) you should see 4 CPU "bars".